# Dialogflow doesn't accept Turkish name

Tags: google-api, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I'm trying to create an intent that takes users name and gives a response with their names and also redirect them to another question. I'm OK with dialogflow doesn't support Turkish language. But even when I enter a Turkish name, for example Meltem, my chatbot doesn't accept my name. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't accept your name.  Can you show us the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

system entities (@sys.*) has some standard pre-defined names. In your case you can create a developer entity instead of using @sys.given-name.  You can build the entity with fewer names and include the option to 'Allow automated expansion'. Check out this link for more information on how to do it https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/dialogflow/vIHMP7wJzWA